# Jooq with SQL Server How to select top N results

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, jooq

In our project we are using two databases, one postgres and one mssql. We are using Jooq in order to query these DBs and with postgres everything was pretty straight forward!

But with mssql we are facing some troubles. The task is to select the top 10 values and let's say that we have the following java code:

```
DSL.using(conn)
.select(USE_CASE.asterisk())                                                                                                                  
.from(USE_CASE)
.where(USE_CASE.RECORD_ACTIVE.eq(true))                                                                                                                                     
.orderBy(USE_CASE.CREATED_ON.desc())                                                                                                                                     
.limit(10)
.offset(0)                                                                                                                                                                                                
.fetch(new UseCaseMapper()))
```

This works like a charm with postgres but on mssql we get the following error:

```
Execution exception[[CompletionException: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: 
SQL [select "park"."dbo"."use_case".* from "park"."dbo"."use_case" where
"park"."dbo"."use_case"."record_active" = ? 
order by "park"."dbo"."use_case"."created_on" desc limit ?]; 
Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.]]
```

I know that for mssql the equivalent query would be something like,

```
select top 10 * 
from use_case 
where record_active = true
order by created_on desc;
```

How can I change my java code to get the limit records in mssql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Correct `SQLDialect`

The exception message hints at the fact that you're still using the PostgreSQL (or some other non-SQL Server) dialect as your catalogs/schemas/tables/columns are quoted using `"double_quotes"`, instead of `[brackets]`.

Just use [`SQLDialect.SQLSERVER`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#SQLSERVER) instead, when running your query on SQL Server. The `LIMIT 10` syntax will then be correctly translated to `TOP 10`.

#### jOOQ Professional Edition vs jOOQ Open Source Edition

From our posted error messages, it is not quite clear how you really configured your jOOQ integration, but if you're using [`DSL.using(Connection)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.sql.Connection-) without explicitly specifying the `SQLDialect`, and jOOQ doesn't correctly "guess" the appropriate `SQLDialect`, this can mostly be because of one of two reasons:

1. You're using some non-standard JDBC URL, which jOOQ doesn't recognise. It thus uses `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`, instead, which produces the wrong SQL syntax for your.
2. You're using the jOOQ Open Source Edition (Maven groupId `org.jooq`) instead of the jOOQ Professional Edition (Maven groupId `org.jooq.pro`, to be installed manually, as it is not distributed via Maven Central), which would also lead to jOOQ using `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`.

   **Notice: this can also happen by accident**, e.g. as a transitive dependency that is being pulled in via Spring Boot or some other framework that already depends on the jOOQ Open Source Edition. In that case, you have to make sure to exclude that transitive dependency from ending up on your classpath. In Maven, you can display all your dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: Hi Lucas, and thanks for your answer! Please note that, we are using org.jooq.pro as maven dependency and from what I see while debuging the JDBCUtils is that the connection url contains the ':sqlserver:' dialect but the returned SQLDialect is SQLDefault.

Comment: During debuging I see the area ```/* [pro] */``` in the dialect method, and the debugger doesn't go in that area... As I already mentioned, we are using the jOOQ Professional Edition (Maven groupId ```org.jooq.pro```) and I believed this wouldn't be the case...

Comment: Maybe you do have the jOOQ Open Source Edition somewhere on your classpath? Do check if you're also accidentally importing `org.jooq` from somewhere (e.g. using `mvn dependency:tree`). For example, Spring Boot has a jOOQ Open Source Edition dependency that you need to exclude. All the package / class names are the same for both editions, but the content is different.

Comment: Thanks again, I was using simpleflatmapper (sfm-jooq) which was also importing a dependency of the open source ```org.jooq```. After excluding it it worked like a charm!

Comment: @kostia: Ah, great to know! I've created an issue to either make the transitive dependency `provided`, or document how to exclude it explicitly: https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/659

Comment: @LukasEder any way in the openSource edition to invoke a method "top" instead of "limit" so that it generates either the SQL key word "top" or "limit" respectively? This will make it agnostic of the SQLDialect for manually building queries via the DSL

Comment: @hovanessyan: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to use the DSL as a pure query builder and I am working against Sybase with the openSource version - as a consultant I don't have control over this. I read that limit will generate 'limit' or 'top' based on the chosen SQLDialect, but was thinking that if you are using SQLDialect.DEFAULT there's no way you can write a query with 'top' in it, which I though was limiting.

Comment: @hovanessyan Sybase support is included in the jOOQ Enterprise Edition. This goes far beyond simple `TOP` clauses. Even if you could tweak this particular syntax, you'd want to tweak 50 other syntaxes soon. I recommend you try upgrading.